# Android image processing and pattern detection

Tags: android, image, image-processing, detection

I'm trying to develop an android app that is capable of detecting led patterns on a screen in order to transmit data.

The screen that the phone will be looking at is a simple 5x19 array of red LEDs. I would like to be able to display numbers, most likely in binary and have the app detect the lit LEDs and determine the number being displayed and their pattern. This would probably require fiducial s similar to those used by QR codes.

Does anyone know what I will need to perform this type of image processing? Are there any good libraries?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: You may want to check out the source code to Zebra Crossing, a barcode/QR/etc. reading app/library for Android, for starters: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has been ported to Android. Check it out